# How to "maintain session" across clients in Oauth2 implementation

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a question relating to different clients connecting to an Oauth2 service (Spring boot Oauth2 auth server) and how can I keep different clients already logged in when using the same browser.

Let's imagine this:

client1 (angularjs web app):

1. Clicks on login button
2. User is redirected to Auth APP
3. User logs into Auth APP
4. Allow the client1
5. User is redirected to client1 with valid token

client2 (magento web app):

Is it possible to be "logged in" here (have a valid token too) without going to the Auth APP?

if not I assume:

1. Clicks on login button
2. User is redirected to Auth APP
3. User is already logged in the Auth APP, goes directly to authorization screen
4. User allows the client
5. Auth APP redirects to client1

So, my question is, is it possible to get rid of the Auth APP redirection in client2 if I have a valid token in client1?
Maybe, JWT tokens with session id or something like that?

Thanks!!